# How to create the multiple symlinks for the folders/files under the same source

Tags: ansible, symlink

I want to create the folder: temp2 which is able to store all the symlinks of the subfolders/files of other foder: temp1. `with_items` can help complete this task, but it needs to list down all the folder/file name as below script shown:

```
- name: "create folder: temp2 to store symlinks"
  file:
    path: "/etc/temp2"
    state: directory

- name: "create symlinks & store in temp2"
  file:
    src: "/etc/temp1/{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "/etc/temp2/{{ item.dest }}"
    state: link
    force: yes
  with_items:
    - { src: 'BEAM', dest: 'BEAM' }
    - { src: 'cfg', dest: 'cfg' }
    - { src: 'Core', dest: 'Core' }
    - { src: 'Data', dest: 'Data' }
```

It is not flexible as the subfolders/files under temp1 would be added or removed, and I need to update above script frequently to keep the symlinks as updated

Is there any way to detect all the files/folder under temp1 automatically instead of maintaining the `with_items` list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can create a list of files using [`find` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/find_module.html):

  > Return a list of files based on specific criteria. Multiple criteria are AND’d together.

  You'll likely need to leave `recurse` set to `false` (default) since you assume subfolders might exist.

  You need to register the results of the module with `register` declaration:

  ```
  register: find
  ```
- In the next step you need to iterate over the `files` list from [the results](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/find_module.html#return-values):

  ```
  with_items: "{{ find.results.files }}"
  ```

  and refer to the value of the `path` key. You already know how to do it.

  You will also need to extract the filename from the path, so that you can append it to the destination path. Use [`basename` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id7) for that.

Comment: Thanks TR. I have followed your answer and it works! Meanwhile, it is also my first time to raise question in Stack. Very impressive by your answer & this platform. Thanks again.

Comment: Attached updated play book for archive or help somebody out:
- name: "create folder: temp2 to store symlinks"
  file:
    path: "/etc/temp2"
    state: directory

- name: "Recursively find file"
  find:
    paths: "/etc/temp1"
    file_type: "any"
  register: find_result

- name: "create symlinks & store in temp2"
  file:
    src: "/etc/temp1/{{ item.path | basename}}"
    dest: "/etc/temp2/{{ item.path | basename }}"
    state: link
    force: yes
  with_items: "{{ find_result.files }}"

Answer (score 9):

The following code works under Ansible-2.8:

```
- name: Find all files in ~/commands
  find:
    paths: ~/commands
  register: find

- name: Create symlinks to /usr/local/bin
  become: True
  file:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    path: "/usr/local/bin/{{ item.path | basename }}"
    state: link
  with_items: "{{ find.files }}"
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Add `file_type: any` to the `find` task to include directories and symlinks, too, not only plain files.